# Rails simple form doen't pass params from input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a list of InvestorTypes (as a radio button) but before each type I should be able to add an explanation of that type. Here is what I've got:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: users_user_experience_level_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <% User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL.each do |level| %>
    <b>Investor type <%= level %></b>
    <%= t("user.description.#{level}") %>
    <%= f.input :experience_level, collection: [level], as: :radio_buttons, label: false %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which gives me expected view:

```
Investor type Beginner
Some explanation of what is going on
[checkobox] type Beginner

Investor type Expert
Some clarification of who is an expert and what ever you want to display here
[checkbox] type Expert

Investor type Institutional
Some clarification of who is an institutional client and some legal stuff
[checkbox] type Institutional
```

But when Submit button is pressed it doesn't pass input value (radio box selection which user chose) into the params:

```
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"experience_level"=>""} permitted: true>
```

[EDIT]

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL = %w[institutional beginner expert].freeze
end
```

Comment: I bet if you click the last radio button it works. Right now I believe the issue is  you are creating a bunch of radio buttons all with the same name and it is combining them top down by name so the last box wins. Usually radio boxes would be created as `<%= f.input :experience_level, collection: User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL, as: :radio_buttons, label: false %>` rather than the loop you are using now.

Comment: @engineersmnky you're right, if I choose the last one it works. I know what the standard approach is but if I use it I will have 3 inputs after each iteration of the initial each. Do you have any idea how to fixed it?

Comment: See https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers and https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're using simple form wrong. The "collection" input in Simple Form is expecting to get an entire list of options, not just one option.

Looping in the way you're doing it is creating one group for each experience level, and each group only has one button in it. So it might visually look correct, but it's not functioning the way you intended. Instead you want to create one group of radio buttons for experience level such that each button changes the value of experience level.

Because you're doing this with significant customization around the appearance, it's probably not a good use of Simple Form, and instead you should fall back to the normal Rails form helpers.

Comment: I guess you are right but how will a regular form helper look like then?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a block to `f.input` to get the simple form wrapper and then use the lower level rails [helpers](http://collection_check_boxes):

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: users_user_experience_level_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    # adds the simple form wrapper 
    <%= f.input :experience_level do %>
      # iterates across the options and yields a input builder to each iteration
      <%= f.collection_checkboxes(:experience_level, User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL, :value_method, :label_method) do |cb| %>
        # There are three special methods available: 
        # object, text and value, 
        # which are the current item being rendered, its text and value methods, respectively.
        <%= t("user.description.#{cb.text}") %>
        <%= cb.check_box %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you don't actually have a model you can use `#itself` to iterate across a flat array:

```
<%= f.collection_checkboxes(:experience_level, User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL, :itself, :itself) do |cb| %>
```

Or an array of pairs:

```
<%= f.collection_checkboxes(:experience_level, User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL.zip(User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL), :first, :last) do |cb| %>
```

Or even a struct.

Comment: In all three cases I'm getting the same error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method collection_select' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: Ah I edited the answer. I guess f.input doesn't yield anything to the block.

Comment: Ok, these are check_boxes (multiple select) instead of radio_buttons. I've changed it to the `collection_radio_buttons` and at the end `cb.radio_button`. But I still need a label, some kind of `<%= cb.check_box, "Investor type #{cb.text}" %>` for each radio button. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: This really depends on what `User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL` is. If you need to have separate labels and values you can use an array of pairs, a struct or even a model. You can output the labels with `<%= cb.label %>`.  See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: It might be helpful with an explaination of the buisness logic you're trying to implement and the data structure.

Comment: Business logic behind this is that user needs to pass Legal Test before get all access to the app. This example is the last step of Legal Test process where user need to declare his experience. There are three investors experience types: beginner, expert, institutional. The view should be displayed in such structure: first line - header with investor type, second line (below investor type): explanation of what the type is (each type should have his own description), third line: radio button alongside which is the type of investor level. Visualised it in my updated question.

Comment: Can you update the question with your except of you User model which shows how `User::USER_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL` is declared?